# Problems with Doctrine and Where

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm having problems with this Query. I want to obtain only the cars with the atribute $categoria and I do this:

```
public function listcategoriaAction($categoria)
    {
        $posts = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()->select('p')->from('CarsCarsBundle:Post',  'p')->where('p.categoria = :categoria')->setParameter('categoria', $categoria)->getQuery()->getResult();

        return $this->render('CarsCarsBundle:Cars:list.html.twig', array('posts' => $posts));
    }
```

But what I recieve is an empty array. Any tips will be appreciated

Comment: Can you tell if $categoria argument is Categoria object or foreign key value (i.e. ID of categoria) ?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I assume that this code is in the controller. I strongly recommend you to avoid putting queries on your controller, instead [use repositories](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html).

I think this error happened because you didn't hydrate previously the category id you received by parameter. This would do the trick:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

//This gets the object from db
$category = $dm->getRepository('CarsCarsBundle:Category')->findOneById($categoria);

if ($category !== null) {

    $posts = $dm->getRepository('CarsCarsBundle:Post')->findOneByCategory($category);

} else {

    //The id received is not on the db.
}
```